# How can i do this smooth transparency transition?

Tags: flutter

Recently I started learning Flutter, and now I got the question:
How can I make this smooth transparency transition? Like here in the picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl4DR.png
(circled in green)

Answer (score 0):

Nest the list in the Stack and put a Container with a white gradient with opacity color over the top of the list.